# variable calling other variable jmeter Beanshell

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I have on counter in jmeter with reference name ${__threadNum}_user_counter,
I want to get the value of this counter in a beanShell Sampler:
the code of my beanshell Sampler is:

```
String threadNumber=(${__threadNum}).toString();
String count=threadNumber+"_user_counter";
vars.put("current_counter_value", ${count});
```

I want to get the value of the counter and set it in a jmeter variable,the problem is that "count" variable is not remplaced by its value setted in the script.
Thank you for help.